Does anyone know how to contact Rav J. Glass who has posted a translation of Netivot Shalom online?
His now non-working email address is still visible where he posted his translation. It used to be ravjglass@yahoo.com. I would like to find out if he has finished or is still working on finishing his translation, and if it is available either elsewhere online or in print.
